# sql pulling in multiple fields

Tags: sql, select, count

I am trying to multiple fields with this code that shows only one count with the code CBEW. 
I am trying to pull the date and the groupid field with it.
Would I just add those into the select and group by?
Sorry - I am newer to SQL!

```
select accnt
    from table
    group by accnt
    having count(*) = 1 and max(code) = 'CBEW';
```

Comment: Do you mean only one count, which is CBEW? Or do you mean only one CBEW count?

Comment: It's checking if "accnt" is there only once AND it's code is CBEW.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.
Here's what I got that works.

```
select accnt, date, groupid
    from table
    group by accnt, date, groupid
    having count(*) = 1 and max(code) = 'CBEW';
```